# Python MQTT improving publish speed for image numpy array

Tags: python, mqtt

I currently have two scripts, one to capture footage and publish the numpy array values (servant.py) and the other script (master.py) to then process those values using opencv for later facial recognition implementations. Problem is that right now it is very slow since the internet packages being sent arrive very delayed to the master script. I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this? of course right now only one frame per second is being sent, so I need the scripts to be able to handle 24 frames per second.

Here are both scripts:

**master.py**

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import numpy as np
import json
import PIL

MQTT_SERVER = "iot.eclipse.org"
MQTT_PATH = "test_channel"

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("connected with result code " + str(rc))
    client.subscribe(MQTT_PATH)

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    dtype = "uint8"
    dshape = (480, 640, 3)
    data = msg.payload
    img_array = np.fromstring(data, dtype=dtype).reshape(dshape)
    img = PIL.Image.fromarray(img_array)
    img.save("img.png")
    img.show()


client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect(MQTT_SERVER, 1883, 60)

client.loop_forever()
```

**servant.py**

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time
import cv2
import numpy
import json

MQTT_SERVER = "iot.eclipse.org"
MQTT_PATH = "test_channel"

mqttc = mqtt.Client()
mqttc.connect(MQTT_SERVER, 1883, 60)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    MQTT_MESSAGE = frame.tostring()
    mqttc.publish(MQTT_PATH, MQTT_MESSAGE)
    mqttc.loop()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: If you want to stream video, MQTT is not the right protocol for you. It was designed to low bandwidth and unreliable connections and not for realtime video.

Comment: @KlausD. could you then please let me know a better way of doing so?

Comment: Also you should not be using the eclipse public test broker for this sort of thing, if you want to tryt this you should be using your own local broker

Comment: As you are sending images, you should consider either sending them as YUV (which takes half the bandwidth relative to RGB) or as MJPEG/JPEG which requires even less bandwidth. You should also measure the time to just acquire images without transmission and just transmit images without acquisition. Then, when you have accurate timing, maybe consider multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to instead stream from the camera using something like cvlc, or gstreamer, and then connect to it from opencv simply (cap = cv2.VideoCapture("http://some_url:some_port") and then you should get a reasonable throughput depending always on the bandwidth, codec, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use `WebcamVideoStream` from `imutils`, compress the image in jpg, publish it as base64:

```
import base64
import cv2
from imutils.video import WebcamVideoStream

cap = WebcamVideoStream(0)
cap.stream.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
cap.stream.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)
cap.start()

while True:
    frame = cap.read()
    if frame is None:
        print("Continue")
        continue

    retval, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
    jpg_as_text = base64.b64encode(buffer).decode('utf-8')
    publish(jpg_as_text)
```